# sitecore popup the edit user roles page

Tags: asp.net, xaml, sitecore

I want to import users in a sitecore backend page, when the csv file upload into site, i need to popup the "edit user roles form" for admin to choose the roles(sitecore/shell/~/xaml/Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Security.SelectRoles.aspx), then get the selected roles to continue the process.

how i could deal with this? 
Any help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The role manager app is in the core db so you need a reference to the core db and then get the item then open the window:

```
var core = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("core");
var roleManagerItem = core.GetItem("/sitecore/content/Applications/Security/Role Manager");
Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Windows.RunApplication(roleManagerItem);
```